# Overriding an abstract method means class abstract class or not in java?

Tags: java

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void area();
}

class B extends A {
    void area(){
        System.out.print("area by class B");
    }
}
```

**Question:-**

Here class `A` is an abstract class and contains an abstract method `area()`.
  then, class `B` `extends` abstract class `A` and also override the abstract
  method `area()`. I read in a book that, If a class contains even a single 
  abstract method then the whole class become abstract class. So, my question 
  is that class B become abstract or not???

Comment: The answer is in the question. `B` has no abstract methods `->` `B` is not abstract.

Comment: No class B is not abstract it implements an abstract method but the method in class B is not abstract because you have given it an implementation. Abstract methods don't have any implementations.

Comment: You have all the information you are looking for [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). Just read the first section.

Answer (score 4):

If you extend A and implement the abstract method (as you have done), B does not have to be abstract.

On a related note, if you only have one abstract method and no concrete methods, you could declare your abstract class instead as an interface like so:

```
interface class A {
   void area();
}

class B implements A {
  void area(){
     System.out.print("area by class B");
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your interface point.  Typically an abstract class has some other implementation behind it, otherwise it's best to keep it as an interface in most cases so that you can still inherit other classes if needed.

Answer (score 3):

No, your class `B` is not abstract, and it doesn't need to be abstract since it doesn't contain any abstract methods; it has a concrete implementation of `area()`.

You *can* still declare it as `abstract`, in which case it would be:

```
abstract class B extends A {
    void area() {
        System.out.print("area by class B");
    }
}
```

So, a class having abstract methods means the class *must* be declared abstract, but a class not having abstract methods doesn't necessarily mean it can't be.

Answer (score 1):

What they mean is,

- If there is any abstract method in a class, then the class should be **declared abstract**
- In your class, class `B` is not `abstract`
- an `abstract` class can have non-abstract methods but an `abstract` method cannot be in a concrete class. i.e. **If a method is abstract, class must be declared abstract**

Answer (score 1):

The class is abstract only if it is declared as 'abstract class'. All other things, like extending abstract classes or containing abstract methods, doesn't means a class to become abstract. Though, will lead to compilation fail.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods.
>
> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, the subclass must also be declared abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Not. Because class B do not have abstract method. What it has is method area() with implementation.

As the class B inherit from A, it must have that method.

Answer (score 0):

`B` hasn't any abstract methods. `B` is just overriding an abstract method and implementing it, so it isn't abstract anymore. So, `B` is not abstract.

Answer (score 0):

If you done something like the following:

```
abstract class A {

   abstract void area();

}

abstract class B extends A {


  abstract void area();

}
```

This would be an abstract method in an abstract class B.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it:

> > What does abstract mean? (literally)
> >      . Something which only exists as an idea.

Now any class with atleast 1 abstract method is an Abstract class.

- `area()` in A only exists as an idea i.e with no real implementation.
- `area()` in B has an implementation and it isn't only an idea anymore.

Hope you understand the concept. In syntax terms an abtract method will have `abstract` as its modifier.

Answer (score 0):

[And also read docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, the subclass must also be declared abstract.

Otherwise **NO.**

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A {
   abstract void area();
}

class B extends A {

}
```

See, above is the case where `class B` should make abstract as it doesn't provides implementation(body) of `area()`.
But in your case, you already gave body to abstract method `area()` from `A`. that is the reason `class B` is not abstract in your case.